# scikits.learn clusterization methods for curve fitting parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I would like some suggestion on the best clusterization technique to be used, using python and scikits.learn. Our data comes from a [Phenotype Microarray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenotype_microarray), which measures the metabolism activity of a cell on various substrates over time. The output are a series of sigmoid curves for which we extract a series of curve parameters through a fitting to a sigmoid function.

We would like to "rank" this activity curves through clusterization, using a fixed number of clusters. For now we are using the k-means algorithm provided by the package, with (init='random', k=10, n_init=100, max_iter=1000). The input is a matrix with n_samples and 5 parameters for each sample. The number of samples can vary, but it is usually around several thousands (i.e. 5'000). The clustering seems efficient and effective, but I would appreciate any suggestion on different methods or on the best way to perform an assessment of the clustering quality.

Here a couple of diagrams that may help:

- the scatterplot of the input parameters (some of them are quite correlated), the color of the single samples is relative to the assigned cluster.
  [image: Scatterplot of input parameters]
- the sigmoid curves from which the input parameters have been extracted, whose color is relative to their assigned cluster
  [image]

**EDIT**

Below some elbow plots and the silhouette score for each number of cluster.
[image: clustering stats]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you noticed the striped pattern in your plots?

This indicates that you didn't normalize your data good enough.

"Area" and "Height" are highly correlated and probably on the largest scale. All the clustering happened on this axis.

You absolutely must:

- perform careful preprocessing
- check that your distance functions produce a meaningful (to you, not just the computer) notion of similarity
- reality-check your results, and check that they aren't too simple, determined e.g. by a single attribute

Don't blindly follow the *numbers*. K-means will happily produce k clusters no matter what data you give. It just optimizes some number. It's up to you to check that the results are useful, and analyze what their semantic meaning is - and it might well be that it just is mathematically a local optimum, but meaningless for your task.

Comment: You are right, the data needed a normalization! I thought the function would have taken care of it... Now the clusterization has more sense and all the parameters seems to be used correctly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Normalization should *not* be automatic. Because the user may want to put more or less emphasis on individual attributes, and the simplest way is to scale them down; in particular for primitive methods such as k-means that don't understand weights or distances. Scaling is a simple way of weighting the attributes then.

Answer (score 5):

For 5000 samples, all methods should work without problem.
The is a pretty good overview [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods).
One thing to consider is whether you want to fix the number of clusters or not.
See the table for possible choices of the clustering algorithm depending on that.

I think spectral clustering is a pretty good method. You can use it for example together with the RBF kernel. You have to adjust gamma, though, and possibly restrict connectivity.

Choices that don't need n_clusters are WARD and DBSCAN, also solid choices.
You can also consult [this chart of my personal opinion](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.de/2013/01/machine-learning-cheat-sheet-for-scikit.html) which I can't find the link to in the scikit-learn docs...

For judging the result: If you have no ground truth of any kind (which I imagine you don't have if this is exploratory) there is no good measure [yet] (in scikit-learn).

There is one unsupervised measure, [silhouette score](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#silhouette-coefficient), but afaik that favours very compact clusters as found by k-means.
There  are stability measures for clusters which might help, though they are not implemented in sklearn yet.

My best bet would be to find a good way to inspect the data and visualize the clustering.
Have you tried PCA and thought about manifold learning techniques?

Comment: Thanks a lot: i've tried the silhouette score and it returns what it looks like a good value (0.55 for n=10). Do you think that keeping a number of clusters like 10 would be a good idea, despite the elbow plots? A higher number of clusters gives us a more granular classification of those curves...

Comment: I am not experienced enough with the silhouette score to tell you if this curve is meaningful, sorry.